# Function rename() remove catalog with files

Tags: php, laravel, move

I try move file from catalog `'storage/cvs/'` to `'storage/r_cvs/'`. I have code:

```
$getOldCV = $worker->cv;
$createCatalogNameCV = $request->name."_".$request->surname;
$createCatalogCV = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $createCatalogNameCV);
// Storage::move('storage/cvs/'.$getOldCV, 'storage/r_cvs/' . $createCatalogCV . '/' . $getOldCV);
rename('storage/cvs/'.$getOldCV, 'storage/r_cvs/' . $createCatalogCV . '/' . $getOldCV);
```

When, I move file `$getOldCV`, file are moved, but script remove all catalog `'storage/cvs/'` with files. I try use `rename()` and Laravel function `Storage::move`, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Laravel, you can use the [`Storage::move()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#storing-files) method:

```
Storage::move(storage_path('csv/' . $getOldCV), storage_path('r_cvs/' . $createCatalogCV . '/' . $getOldCV));
```

Or `File::move()`. It is different from the `Storage::move()`:

```
File::move(storage_path('csv/' . $getOldCV), storage_path('r_cvs/' . $createCatalogCV . '/' . $getOldCV));
```

Also, make sure file permissions are correct for the `storage` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might do a copy() and unklink() instead:

```
copy('storage/cvs/'.$getOldCV, 'storage/r_cvs/' . $createCatalogCV . '/' . $getOldCV);
unlink('storage/cvs/'.$getOldCV);
```

Answer (score 1):

I change [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) to [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), now script work correct